# How to indexing an array inside array using Nativescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, listview, nativescript

I have this JSON that call from API.

How to indexing an array inside array using Nativescript

```
JS: cart [{
JS:   "_id": "5d3988cd287bad2943686920",
JS:   "userid": "11E76234942299FCC13FFA163EDC2079",
JS:   "products": [
JS:     {
JS:       "product_ID": "102",
JS:       "price": 20,
JS:       "quantiy": 2
JS:     },
JS:     {
JS:       "product_ID": "103",
JS:       "price": 20,
JS:       "qty": 3
JS:     },
JS:     {
JS:       "product_ID": "104",
JS:       "price": 20,
JS:       "qty": 3
JS:     }
JS:   ]
JS: }, {
JS:   "_id": "5d399ec8f8514f2a9a68da30",
JS:   "userid": "11E76234942299FCC13FFA163EDC2079",
JS:   "products": [
JS:     {
JS:       "product_ID": "102",
JS:       "price": 20,
JS:       "qty": 3
JS:     }
JS:   ]
JS: }]
```

I want to increment qty like this function:

```
  incrementQty(product_ID) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cart[i].products.length; i++) {                  
                        this.cart[i].products[i].qty++;              
           }  
    }
```

`this.cart[i].products.length;` show only 3

Increment only first product `product_ID:102`

How to increment qty in each row ?

Comment: Wait, if there are 2 objects in `cart`, from which object should the `qty` be increased?

Comment: I want to increment each btn  that I click. If I click btn with _id '5d399ec8f8514f2a9a68da30' and product_ID:102 I want to increment it. If i click btn with "_id": "5d3988cd287bad2943686920" and  "product_ID": "103" I want to increment it. My function for the moment increment only first prod in first obj. I can't understan why

Comment: Hmm, ok. And how does `incrementQty()` know which button `_id` is the one that is selected? That method only takes in the product id, and not _id?

Comment: I put like `incrementQty(_id,product_ID) { ... }` but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify your `incrementQty` method such that it takes in 2 parameters, `_id` and `product_id`. To achieve the desired results, you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter through `cart` based on the `_id` and `product_ID`.

```js
const cart = [{
   "_id": "5d3988cd287bad2943686920",
   "userid": "11E76234942299FCC13FFA163EDC2079",
   "products": [
     {
       "product_ID": "102",
       "price": 20,
       "qty": 2
     },
     {
       "product_ID": "103",
       "price": 20,
       "qty": 3
     },
     {
       "product_ID": "104",
       "price": 20,
       "qty": 3
     }
   ]
 }, {
   "_id": "5d399ec8f8514f2a9a68da30",
   "userid": "11E76234942299FCC13FFA163EDC2079",
   "products": [
     {
       "product_ID": "102",
       "price": 20,
       "qty": 3
     }
   ]
 }];

 const incrementQty = (id, productId) => {
   const item = cart.filter(obj => obj._id === id)[0];
   const selectedProduct = item.products.filter(obj=> obj.product_ID === productId)[0];
   Number(selectedProduct.qty++);
 };

incrementQty('5d3988cd287bad2943686920', '102')
console.log(cart);
```

In addition, you must have mispelt one of the properties of the first product with the `id` of 102. It should be `qty` instead of `quantiy`.

Comment: Please see Demo https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=j13C1a